How to compile a project for Windows that uses winsock2 on Linux?
I use mingw-w64 on Linux to compile a cmake project for Windows, but I get a bunch of errors during the process like “WSACleanup was not declared in this scope”. My CMakeLists:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX x86_64-w64-mingw32)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-g++)
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-windres)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX})

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Windows")
    enable_language("RC")
    set (WIN32_RESOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/usbclient.rc)
endif()

project ("usbclient")
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs)
add_executable (usbclient usbclient.cpp ssh.cpp tcpmodule.cpp utils.cpp ${WIN32_RESOURCES})

target_link_libraries(usbclient PUBLIC ChilkatRel_x64 WS2_32 MsWSock AdvAPI32)

part of the .h file that includes <winsock2.h> and <ws2tcpip.h>:
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define _WINSOCKAPI_

#include "json.hpp"
#include "utils.h"
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <ws2tcpip.h>
#endif
#include "ssh.h"

I tried to connect ws2_32.lib, which I got from Windows Kits, but it didn’t help

Show the full error output and compiler commandline (set(VERBOSE 1) in cmake or cmake --verbose --build $BUILDDIR). Also show us which headers are included in the failing file

did you include <winsock2.h> in your code? Guard it with #ifdef _WIN32.

yes, I included <winsock2.h> and <ws2tcpip.h>

the errors mainly occur in winsock2.h. and most of them are "* was not declared in this scope" (I would show you the whole list of errors, but there are too many of them to add to the question)

Can you reproduce the errors when compiling a file containing #include <winsock2.h> and nothing else? What if you compile manually in the terminal instead of using cmake?

@HolyBlackCat if compile using "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc tcpmodule.cpp -lstdc++" a file including only <winsock2.h>,  and one main function (with test cout), then no errors occur

Then try to compile the same file using cmake. If you get errors, switch cmake to verbose mode and see what compiler commands it runs.

@HolyBlackCat compilation via cmake also did not cause errors

Then figure out what's the difference between the test program and your actual one. Start with the things that happen before including winsock.

Avoid getting stuff from Microsoft and mixing that with MinGW-w64. If you have MinGW-w64 on your system it should come with a libws2_32.a file and normally the MinGW-w64 toolkit (x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc) should know where to find it if you just specify linker flag -lws2_32. Also make sure to tell CMake to cross-build for Windows (-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Windows).
